# Does Solace support DTO with MQTT?

Tags: solace

I have many devices sending data to the backend server via Solace using MQTT.  As I need to handle large volume of incoming messages, I am thinking of starting a few listener instances to process the incoming messages. But, it does not help as MQTT pub/sub is effectively a 1-to-many messaging, i.e. the same message will be delivered to all subscribing listeners.  I know Solace supports DTO but does it support DTO using MQTT?  If so, how do I do that?  If not, any suggestion how I could start multiple listeners to process the large amount of incoming messages? What I have in mind now is to create Queues with non-exclusive delivery that subscribe to these topics.  Not sure whether there are other better way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The MQTT protocol does not have a feature to deliver messages to consumers in a round robin manner.

I'm assuming that your back-end servers are not using MQTT to receive the messages.

You can either:

1. Distribute the load by publishing to different topics.
2. Have a non-exclusive queue subscribe to the topic, and let the queue distribute the messages to the consumers in a round robin fashion.

Note that option 2, is the correct option if your publishers are publishing QoS 1 messages. Messages to be consumed by your back-end servers will be spooled in the queue if all of your consumers go offline. Without the queue, messages will be discarded if there are no online consumers.

Comment: How about if I create a separate VPN and bridge the messages over with DTO?  Then, my JCSMP clients subscribe to topics from this separate VPN. But, I doubt it will work because the original MQTT messages are not sent with DTO set (since MQTT does not support DTO).  Can confirm?  Thanks!